# Why isn't WebRequest.GetResponseAsync() async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webrequest

As far as I know WebRequest.GetResponseAsync() can be awaited and is asynchonous.
But when I look at its source code at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs,99a2a9c8ebc067dc
it isn't defined with the "async" keyword.

I thought you cannot await a method that is not defined as "async"?

Comment: The `async` keyword is not required in order for a method to be async in nature. The keyword makes it *easier* to write flow control statements and error handling, but it is by no means necessary *if you know what you're doing*. The important part is that the method returns a `Task`.

Comment: The `async` keyword has no real function other than to enable the `await` keyword. And you don't need the `await` keyword either when you don't want or need to await tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought you cannot await a method that is not defined as "async"?

This is a kind of "shorthand" way of thinking about it that can be useful while initially learning `async`, but falls apart when you gain more knowledge about `async`/`await`. There are two concepts that are not quite right in this sentence.

First, code cannot `await` a method. What actually happens is that the method is called, exactly like any other method. That method returns a value - an *awaitable* type - and it is that return value that is actually awaited. It's common for us to talk about "awaiting a method", but that's just shorthand for "calling a method and awaiting its return value", which is more accurate but too awkward for most conversation.

Second, `async` is just *one way* to create an awaitable return value (which can then be awaited). There are several other ways as well. For example, `Task<T>.Factory.FromAsync` is commonly used if you have an API that uses the [older APM asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm), and you want to use it with `await`. In that case, you would normally [write wrapper methods that return `Task<T>` and are implemented using `Task<T>.Factory.FromAsync` (without `async`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#from-apm-to-tap). Another common approach is to use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, which [can create a `Task<T>` around any kind of logical "future event"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/).

To put it another way, `async` is an implementation detail. This concept is further enforced by the fact that interface methods can be declared as returning `Task` and awaited, but only method *implementations* can be declared with `async`.

Comment: Just like with iterators (the other syntactic sugar which the compiler transforms into state machines), another very common pattern is a public wrapper function around a private helper function that uses the async/await deferred execution.  The wrapper is eagerly evaluated and any exceptions it throws are reported synchronously instead of being captured into the Task.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question; on the [API browser page for GetRequestStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-webrequest-getrequeststreamasync), the signature is:

> public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.IO.Stream> GetRequestStreamAsync ();

and I thought "how can it be possible to call a non-async method using await"?  I followed this question down the rabbit hole to [the documentation page for await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await), which says:

> The operand of the await operator is usually of one of the following .NET types: Task, Task, ValueTask, or ValueTask. However, any awaitable expression can be the operand of the await operator. For more information, see the Awaitable expressions section of the C# language specification.

The constraint is actually that await must be used within an async method, but its operand can be any "awaitable expression"!  The implication of GetRequestStreamAsync itself not being "async" just means that it doesn't contain any await calls itself, I'd have thought.  But then how does it safely implement asynchronous functionality, I thought?

So then I went one step farther and looked at [the source browser for WebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync](https://source.dot.net/System.Net.Requests/R/7bf05f7c95bc83e4.html), and the signature of the method there is:

> public virtual async Task GetRequestStreamAsync()

So this makes me think that the API browser (which says it's not async) is out of sync with the actual implementation, where it IS async!  Hm.  I hope an override of a virtual function (as in HttpWebRequest overriding WebRequest) does not change the async-ness of the method.